# Implement client server architecture with WCF for a project that has used LLBL gen pro 2.6

Tags: c#, wcf, client, llblgenpro, llblgen

I have a project that was developed using LLBL GEN PRO 2.6. Its Self Hosting method is used for the project.

UI has also used the DAL(LLBL GEN PRO auto generated set of class which does most of the Business layer and 100% of the Data Access Layer things).

Now I want to move this project to Client server architecture with IIS hosted WCF.

I want to use the LLBL GEN PRO created project as it is (Without using dataAccess Adapters).

Comment: What is the question

Comment: how to expose a wcf service using llbl gen proc without using adapters